# chrome extension/// my code is running more than one time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

Sorry for my poor English Grammar.

I'm studying to make a chrome extension.

I want to detect current tab url changing

**manifest.json**

```
 "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["public/js/background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    }
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    console.log(tab.url);
});
```

when I change current tab's url, in console, 3 or 4 logs are printed

I don't understand this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is fired several times, 2 at a minimum, because it does not only signify the URL change, but also the state change.

Notice that [the description](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) says that `changeInfo.url` is present when the URL actually changes. So, you can do something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if(changeInfo.url) {
    console.log(changeInfo.url);
  }
});
```

If you only want to track navigation, you might want to look at the [`webNavigation` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation).